# Sitecore Save Check Revision Custom processor

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor, pipelines, processor

Using `Sitecore 10`
Experience editor save is not working.

So i got a custom processor to use instead of the default one from sitecore support. I created a class and added the processor and also a patch config as below

```
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
<pipelines>
<saveUI>
        <processor type="Custom.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.SaveItem, Custom" patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.CheckRevision, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
</saveUI>
</pipelines>
 </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

But it seems the custom processor is not getting called.

Comment: Please open /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx and make sure that your config was applied.

Comment: Yes i can see my config there. But the custom processor is not getting called or excuted

Comment: Save button on Experience Editor calls `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.Requests.SaveItem.CallServerSavePipeline`, which call `saveUI` pipeline. It means that the saveUI pipeline should be executed.

How do you check that your processor is not executed? Did you add some code that enters debug information to the log file? Or did you attach to the process and try to debug it?

Comment: I added the custom processor by creating a class. Then added a config patch like above. I added some logs in the processor and they did not come in logs, So I understood the processor is not getting called and the issue is also not fixed. My local does not have issue. Soafter adding the processor, I copied my project dll and the patch and testing in another environemnt. But didnt work